# Cannot publish service with editable layer

Tags: feature-service

We have several services published, up and running for our on-line viewers.  However, we are trying to publish a service containing our bus stops, that can be brought up on a mobile device for editing in the field.  We have a user set-up called "webedit" and the layer in the mxd is pointing to this datasource.  When publishing, we check "Feature Access" and "Mobile Data" under the Capablilities.   Start Service automatically is checked. Upon analyzing, only minor errros are reported - data extent, tags, summary, draws at all scales, things that shouldn't be deal breakers. It shows as published, but then gives the message that the service did not start and that it must be started thru server manager.  When this is attempted, we get a rather non-descript "failure to start service".  The last time we tried, we discovered we needed a GlobalID, and this has been added to the table. The error logs are no help either.  All our other services publish fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Server are you using?  Could you edit this detail into your Question, please?